# Parenting and Unparenting in OpenMaya?

Tags: python, maya

Would be possible to help me?
In fact the reparentNode and addChild works reparenting and parenting… but there is some way to keep the node at the same place? Im sending my code:

```
q1 = getMObject("locator1")
q2 = getMObject("locator2")

p = new_om.MFnDagNode(q1)
p.addChild(q2)

u = new_om.MDagModifier()

u.reparentNode(q2)
u.doIt()
```

thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that comes for free in OpenMaya. Simply get/store the transformation matrix in MSpace.kWorld before reparenting, and reapply after parenting.

Comment: hi Klaudikus,
thanks for replying.. this function already get the matrix transformation and store it.. the problem is that I have to:
1) parent B to A
2) move A
3) unparent B
so when I unparent B, B should stay where A brought him.. any idea?

Comment: Get the transform matrix of B in world space just before unparenting B. Reapply in world space after  unparenting.